# My son doesn't feel cold

Tags: body-temperature, senses

My son doesn't like to wear cloths at home. In winters, he lets me shut the heat in his room because he feels hot. The most sentences I hear from him are:

- It's burning
- I am not hungry

Sitting in his room wearing thick cloth, I still feel cold. But whenever my son coming back from school, he will be only in his underpants and will be sitting there all day and never feel cold.
He also doesn't eat much. He can skip a few meals whenever he doesn't have his favorite food. He can also eat a lot when he likes the food.
Should I need to worry about anything?

Comment: Welcome to health SE :-) Personal medical questions are off-topic for this site, since there is no way for us to establish a diagnosis over the internet. You have noticed something about your son that seems out of the ordinary - the best course of action is to consult a physician in person.

Comment: I recommend seeing his pediatrician/family med doc.  Heat/cold intolerance and abnormal appetite are 2 constitutional symptoms that may or may not be significant. It could be a number of things - from hyperthyroidism to a totally normal preference for cooler temperatures and poor eating habits.  As @Volker mentions below, write down the actual temperatures that he finds tolerable and intolerable. Write down any other symptoms, or any changes you've noticed.  Also keep a food diary for at least several days (what foods, amounts, and at what times).  Bring that info with you to clinic.

Answer (score 1):

Body temperature actually does not vary a lot between individuals contrary to Lakshmi's answer unless you have a fever. More information is needed to answer the question. Age, body weight / height and calorie intake per day as well as a recent history of unintentional weight gain or weight loss for starters. How long has this been going on for and are there other symptoms? Is your son actually unwell?
Also: It may be you whose temperature perception is off. It is well known that women, especially as they get older are less tolerant to colder temperatures than men. What is the actual temperature in your house and in his room? Maybe he is trying to escape from the excessive heat you create to be comfortable.

Comment: Actually I am dad. My son is in middle school. He looks healthier than I am. I touch his body and feel his body temperature a little warmer than my hand. I have asked him if he is born like this or has developed over time. He said he has developed it. We set our room temperature as 70. I don't know what his room's temperature is but we feel every room is comfortable except his. His mom and sisters feel the same as I do. I wonder if anyone is the same as my son.

Comment: He looks a little bigger than his boy classmates, no sudden weight gain or loss. Before we lived in apartment in Canada the whole time where because the building has to ensure the coldest unit reach certain temperature, most of the units are very very warm. Winter's apartments in Canada, everyone wears summer clothes at home. Now we have moved to a house in the States, where we set the temperature ourselves, I then started to notice this.

Answer (score 0):

A common sense or intuition question: Does your son appear ill to you? Does he look or feel unwell?

Examples of symptoms that would suggest he has some illness:

- His behavior has changed, so he was not always like this
- Increased body temperature (did you measure it?)
- Night sweats
- Fatigue
- Paleness
- Cough
- Changed bowel habits
- Pain (headache, stomach pain...)
- Rash

One disorder, among others, with feeling of warmth and appetite changes is hyperthyroidism ([Endocrinoweb](https://www.endocrineweb.com/conditions/hyperthyroidism/hyperthyroidism-symptoms))